# is it possible to run a programm compiled with g++ 4.6.3(ubuntu) on fedora10 g++ 4.3.2

Tags: gcc, g++

my question is whether it is possible to run a program compiled with gcc/g++ 4.6.3 on ubuntu12.04 on a fedora 10 release with gcc/g++ 4.3.2..

if i run it, i always get

```
'./myprogram: symbol lookup error: usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol:          _ZNSt8messagesIcE2idE, version GLIBCXX_3.4'
```

`'ldd -r myprogram'` shows me that lot's of symbols are undefined.

i think that this has something to do with the libgcc_s.so.1 and the ld-2.X.so.

what i tried already:

> updating the gcc and g++ on fedora
>  downgrading gcc and g++ on
>   ubuntu to 4.3
>  compiling myprogram with gcc/g++ 4.4.7
>  tried
>   different libstdc++.so.6.0.XX --> XX = 13(GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found)
>   ,XX = 16(undefined symbol)

but without luck :-(

so my questions: is it even possible to get my program to execute or can i stop trying because it's not? or are there any tools which can provide the compatibility?

thanks 
greetings

Comment: Can you not recompile the program on the target system?

Comment: i thought of this too, but it's a cross development project with lot's of dependencies and so on.The target system is a very minimal fedora system with 1GB CompactFlash card.I already had to build wxWidgets libraries on the target system. this would be the last thing i wanna try.